# How can I identify which processes are generating UDP traffic on Linux?

Tags: linux, process, traffic, udp

My machine is continously making udp dns traffic request. what i need to know is the PID of the process generating this traffic.

The normal way in TCP connection is to use netstat/lsof and get the process associated at the pid.

Is UDP the connection is stateles, so, when i call netastat/lsof I can see it only if the UDP socket is opened and it's sending traffic.

I have tried with `lsof -i UDP` and with `nestat -anpue`, but I can't find wich process is doing that request because i need to call lsof/netstat exactly when the udp traffic is sended, if i call lsof/netstat before/after the udp datagram is sended is impossible to view the opened UDP socket.

Call netstat/lsof exactly when 3/4 udp packet is sended is IMPOSSIBLE.

How I can identify the infamous process? I have already inspected the traffic to try to identify the sended PID from the content of the packet, but is not possible to identify it from the contect of the traffic.

Anyone can help me ?

I'm root on this machine FEDORA 12 Linux noise.company.lan 2.6.32.16-141.fc12.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jul 7 04:49:59 UTC 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Linux auditing can help.  It will at least locate users and processes making datagram network connections.  UDP packets are datagrams.

First, install the `auditd` framework on your platform and ensure that `auditctl -l` returns something, even if it says that no rules are defined.

Then, add a rule to watch the system call `socket()` and tag it for easy finding later (`-k`).  I need to assume that you are on a 64-bit architecture, but you can substitute `b32` in place of the `b64` if you aren't.

```
auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -F a0=2 -F a1\&=2 -S socket -k SOCKET
```

You have to pick through man pages and header files to build this, but what it captures is essentially this system call: `socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|X, Y)`, where the third parameter is unspecified but frequently zero.  `PF_INET` is 2 and `SOCK_DGRAM` is 2.  TCP connections would use `SOCK_STREAM` which would set `a1=1`.  (`SOCK_DGRAM` in the second parameter may be ORed with `SOCK_NONBLOCK` or `SOCK_CLOEXEC`, hence the `&=` comparison.)  The `-k SOCKET` is our keyword we want to use when searching audit trails later.  It can be anything, but I like to keep it simple.

Let a few moments go by and review the audit trails.  Optionally, you could force a couple of packets by pinging a host out on the net, which will cause a DNS lookup to occur, which uses UDP, which should trip our audit alert.

```
ausearch -i -ts today -k SOCKET
```

And output similar to the section below will appear.  I'm abbreviating it to highlight the important parts

```
type=SYSCALL ... arch=x86_64 syscall=socket success=yes exit=1 a0=2 a1=2 ... pid=14510 ... auid=zlagtime uid=zlagtime ... euid=zlagtime ... comm=ping exe=/usr/bin/ping key=SOCKET
```

In the above output, we can see that the `ping` command caused the socket to be opened.  I could then run `strace -p 14510` on the process, if it was still running.  The `ppid` (parent process ID) is also listed in case it is a script that spawns the problem child a lot.

Now, if you have a lot of UDP traffic, this isn't going to be good enough and you'll have to resort to [OProfile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/) or [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/), both of which are currently beyond my expertise.

This should help narrow things down in the general case.

When you are done, remove the audit rule by using the same line you used to create it, only substitute `-a` with `-d`.

```
auditctl -d exit,always -F arch=b64 -F a0=2 -F a1\&=2 -S socket -k SOCKET
```

Comment: i will try it, but i think is the right answer.

Comment: This isn't picking up traffic being dropped by iptables, at least for me.

Comment: +1 for the simplicity compared to the systemtap method (which is more analytical, but needs kernel devel packages)

Answer (score 24):

You can use netstat, but you need the right flags, and it only works if the process that is sending the data is still alive.  It won't find the traces of something that came briefly to life, sent UDP traffic, then went away.  It also requires local root privileges.  That said:

Here's me starting an ncat on my local host, sending UDP traffic to port 2345 on a (non-existent) machine 10.11.12.13:

```
[madhatta@risby]$ ncat -u 10.11.12.13 2345 < /dev/urandom
```

Here's some tcpdump output proving that the traffic is going:

```
[root@risby ~]# tcpdump -n -n port 2345
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
12:41:32.391750 IP 192.168.3.11.57550 > 10.11.12.13.2345: UDP, length 8192
12:41:32.399723 IP 192.168.3.11.57550 > 10.11.12.13.2345: UDP, length 8192
12:41:32.401817 IP 192.168.3.11.57550 > 10.11.12.13.2345: UDP, length 8192
12:41:32.407051 IP 192.168.3.11.57550 > 10.11.12.13.2345: UDP, length 8192
12:41:32.413492 IP 192.168.3.11.57550 > 10.11.12.13.2345: UDP, length 8192
12:41:32.417417 IP 192.168.3.11.57550 > 10.11.12.13.2345: UDP, length 8192
```

**Here's the useful bit**, using netstat with the -a flag (to see port details) and the -p flag to see process ID details.  It's the -p flag that requires root privileges:

```
[root@risby ~]# netstat -apn|grep -w 2345
udp        0      0 192.168.3.11:57550          10.11.12.13:2345            ESTABLISHED 9152/ncat
```

As you can see, pid 9152 is fingered as having a connection open to port 2345 on the specified remote host.  Netstat helpfully also runs that through ps and tells me the process name is `ncat`.

Hopefully that's of some use.

Comment: really nice done! :thumbup:

Comment: There's a catch though.  If the problem is caused by a shell script spawning a subprocess that does the DNS lookup and that process quickly exits, then the source port (57550 above) will change all the time.  In this case, the technique will not work and you'll have to take more drastic measures.  Additionally, your netstat should have done a `grep -w 57550` because multiple processes could be doing DNS lookups to the same server.  Your method would not distinguish them.

Comment: I agree with both of your objections, zerolagtime (but thanks for your kind words anyway, ThorstenS!).

Answer (score 23):

I had exactly the same problem and unfortunately `auditd` didn't do much for me.

I had traffic from some of my servers going towards google DNS addresses, `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`. Now, my network admin has mild OCD and he wanted to clean all the unnecessary traffic since we have our intern DNS caches.  He wanted to disable outgoing port 53 for everyone except those cache servers.

So, after failing with `auditctl`, I dig into [`systemtap`](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/). I come up with the following script:

```
# cat >> udp_detect_domain.stp <<EOF
probe udp.sendmsg {
  if ( dport == 53 && daddr == "8.8.8.8" ) {
    printf ("PID %5d (%s) sent UDP to %15s 53\n", pid(), execname(), daddr)
  }
}
EOF
```

Then simply run:

```
stap -v udp_detect_domain.stp
```

This is the output that I got:

```
PID  3501 (python) sent UDP to  8.8.8.8 53
PID  3501 (python) sent UDP to  8.8.8.8 53
PID  3506 (python) sent UDP to  8.8.8.8 53
```

That's it! After changing `resolv.conf` those PIDs didn't pick up the changes.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This will fail unless you install the debug symbols for the kernel (see this post for a followup https://stackoverflow.com/a/45991767/322049)

Answer (score 8):

Here's a systemtap option, using the netfilter probes available in stap verson 1.8 and later.  See also `man probe::netfilter.ip.local_out`.

```
# stap -e 'probe netfilter.ip.local_out {
  if (dport == 53) # or parametrize
      printf("%s[%d] %s:%d\n", execname(), pid(), daddr, dport)
}'
ping[24738] 192.168.1.10:53
ping[24738] 192.168.1.10:53
^C
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use a net-sniffer like tcpdump or wireshark to view the DNS requests. The contents of the query can give an idea of what program is issuing them.

Comment: no information in the traffic sniffed i just already view.

Comment: No info? Empty packets? What I meant was, if something is attempting to resolve updates.java.sun.com or rss.cnn.com you might usefully infer something from it.

Comment: dns query searching for the internal proxy. right now i found wich process is, but the question stil alive for a general problem solving technics

Comment: lsof -i  | awk '/UDP/'

Answer (score 4):

Be aware that when using autitctl, nscd for example uses a slightly different parameter in the socket system call, when doing a DNS query:

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP)
```

So to make sure you catch those queries in addition to the ones that were mentioned above, you can add an additional filter, with the same name if you want:

```
auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -F a0=2  -F a1=2050 -S socket -k SOCKET
```

Here 2050 is a bitwise OR of *SOCK_DGRAM* (2) and *SOCK_NONBLOCK* (2048).

Then the search will find both those filters with the same key, `SOCKET`:

```
ausearch -i -ts today -k SOCKET
```

The hex values for the socket constants I found here: https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#pkg-constants

As I have no reputation points to comment I added this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Auditd framework, and initially it didn't look very promising, as all I thought it was telling me was that process sent a UDP packet.

Then tried SystemTap, and initially it worked, but then it started reporting the destination port and address as 0.0.0.0 and 0 on some packets, but not others.  Others have had that [problem](https://totem3-hatenablog-jp.translate.goog/entry/2019/05/04/010653?_x_tr_sl=ja&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=sc) too.  Rebooting and clearing caches didn't help, gave up.

Then looked into Dtrace, and quickly transitioned to Perf (thanks, [Brendan Gregg](https://www.brendangregg.com/)!)  However, couldn't figure out how to do the same task.

Then found another [Auditd solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/213265/what-program-sent-which-packet-to-the-network) and apparently Auditd does actually record the destination ports and addresses, but embedded in hex:

```
$ sudo bash
# date +%s; \
  auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64  -S connect -k sendmsg; \
  nslookup serverfault.com 8.8.8.8 > /dev/null; \
  auditctl -d exit,always -F arch=b64  -S connect -k sendmsg;\
  date +%s
1664829661
1664829661

# grep 1664829661 /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep -C1 -m1 08080808

type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1664829661.285:24390): arch=c000003e syscall=46 success=yes exit=33 a0=14 a1=7f0c3b3f59b0 a2=0 a3=7f0c41415170 items=0 ppid=1523 pid=10483 auid=1003 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=2 comm="isc-worker0000" exe="/usr/bin/nslookup" key="sendmsg"
type=SOCKADDR msg=audit(1664829661.285:24390): saddr=02000035080808080000000000000000
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1664829661.285:24390): proctitle=6E736C6F6F6B7570007365727665726661756C742E636F6D00382E382E382E38
```

The saddr=02000035080808080000000000000000 breaks down into:

- 0200 -- PF_INET
- 0035 -- port 53 (DNS)
- 08080808 -- ip address 8.8.8.8

The proctitle decodes as:

```
# echo 6E736C6F6F6B7570007365727665726661756C742E636F6D00382E382E382E38 | xxd -p -r | xargs -0

nslookup serverfault.com 8.8.8.8
```

Also confirmed it with arbitrary destination ip 1.2.3.4:

```
type=SOCKADDR msg=audit(1664830858.835:24624): saddr=02000035010203040000000000000000
* 0200 -- PF_INET
* 0035 -- port 53 (DNS)
* 01020304 -- ip address 1.2.3.4
```

So... go have fun tracking down processes that send UDP packets!  :-)

---

EDIT: Apparently `ausearch` is a darn useful tool; it converts the arguments to something approximately human-readable:

```
# ausearch -i -ts today -k sendmsg | more
...
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(2022-10-03 13:58:51.203:24596) : proctitle=nslookup serverfault.com 8.8.4.4 
type=SOCKADDR msg=audit(2022-10-03 13:58:51.203:24596) : saddr={ fam=inet laddr=8.8.4.4 lport=53 } 
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(2022-10-03 13:58:51.203:24596) : arch=x86_64 syscall=sendmsg success=yes exit=33 a0=0x15 a1=0x7f42723ba2e0 a2=0x0 a3=0x7f42723ba520 items=0 ppid=1523 pid=15000 auid=randomuser uid=root gid=root euid=root suid=root fsuid=root egid=root sgid=root fsgid=root tty=pts0 ses=2 comm=isc-worker0000 exe=/usr/bin/nslookup key=sendmsg 
...
```

---

EDIT2:
Here's live printing of the requests, filtered to just destination port 53 (IDK why destination addr+port is `laddr` and `lport`, it just is):

```
# tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log       \
  | ausearch -i -k sendmsg               \
  | grep -B1 --line-buffered 'lport=53 ' \
  | sed 's/ : / :\n   /'
 
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(02/14/2023 16:20:05.022:135695) :
   proctitle=dig +short www.google.com @8.8.8.8 
type=SOCKADDR msg=audit(02/14/2023 16:20:05.022:135695) :
   saddr={ fam=inet laddr=8.8.8.8 lport=53 }
```

---

EDIT3:
And here's the TCP version, since DNS can do UDP or TCP:

```
# auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S connect -k MYCONNECT
# tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log \
  | ausearch -i -k MYCONNECT \
  | grep -B1 --line-buffered 'lport=53 ' \
  | sed 's/ : / :\n   /'

type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(02/14/2023 16:32:18.168:208235) :
   proctitle=/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/run_test.py 
type=SOCKADDR msg=audit(02/14/2023 16:32:18.168:208235) :
   saddr={ fam=inet laddr=127.0.0.1 lport=53 }
```

Making it ignore 127.0.0.1 is left as an exercise for the reader. :-)