# On Linux, how can I tell which process is sending Ethernet packets?

Tags: linux, debian, network-monitoring

I'm running gkrellm which shows that some process on my Debian Linux system is writing approx 500KB/s to eth0.  I'd like to find out which process it is.  I know a little bit about netstat, but it shows a gazillion open TCP connections and I can't seem to make it produce any information about traffic.

Does anybody know how I can get a list of processes that are actually *using* the eth0 interface so that I can track down the offender?

---

**FOLLOWUP**: The Debian Linux distribution contains a `nethogs` package which solves this problem definitively.  Related tools that are not quite on the mark include `iftop`, `netstat`, and `lsof`.

Comment: `iptraf` is good

Comment: This worked for me for very short-lived UDP exchanges: https://serverfault.com/a/683327/119360

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I prefer [nethogs](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs). It's a small ncurses-based console program that displays per-process network traffic status in a convenient way.

Answer (score 19):

`netstat -ptu` will give you the owning process ids (along with standard netstat info) for all tcp and udp conections. (Normal users will not be able to id all processes.)

If something is sending out a fair amount of constant traffic you should see it on `Recv-Q` or `Send-Q` columns 2 and 3 respectively.

Examples:
`Recv-Q`
`sudo watch -n .1 'netstat -tup | grep -E "^[tc,ud]p[6]{0,1}" | sort -nr -k2'`

`Send-Q`
`sudo watch -n .1 'netstat -tup | grep -E "^[tc,ud]p[6]{0,1}" | sort -nr -k3'`

If you suspect that that process is being triggered by another process `ps axf`.

Comment: (Not that the -u flag in necessary if you know that you are looking for TCP connections.)

Answer (score 5):

A more manual operation if you are looking for just a process sending/receiving data would be to run the `lsof` command. This will list all open files for each process which will include network connections as they are file descriptors to the o.s.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Install `iftop` (simple text-based) or `ntop` (graphical).

Comment: `iftop` only display bandwidth usage on an interface.

Comment: It shows much more than that. By default, it breaks it down by host.

Comment: Can it list all processes that are using an interface? If so, could you please show us the command and options?

Comment: Not directly. But once you find the host, you can find the process, for example with `netstat -pn`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `tcpdump` to sniff some packets on this interface:

```
# tcpdump -vv -s0 -i eth0 -c 100 -w /tmp/eth0.pcap
```

Copy to client and open with Wireshark to see what happens.

Comment: Not the easiest way to get simple stats but anything even slightly more complicated and wireshark will shine!