# How to know which process was using a port after it enters TIME_WAIT state?

Tags: netstat

On Linux, is there a way to figure out what process was using a port,
before it went into `TIME_WAIT` state.

When I use `netstat -tnp` I just see two end points, but no process information.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38805             127.0.0.1:111               TIME_WAIT   -
```

Answer (score 3):

No, the system just doesn't keep track of this.

[TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) shows quite clearly that closed sockets which fall in the TIME_WAIT state are instantly re-assigned to process 0 (System).

---

Sorry, I misread your question; the above answer refers to **Windows** systems.
However, I think the same happens on Linux systems, too.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, tracing socket opens greatly helps me to spot TIME_WAIT states (since typically means that my application is repeatedly creating sockets)

Based on [how i can identify which process is making UDP traffic on linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/192893/how-i-can-identify-which-process-is-making-udp-traffic-on-linux) , I tried auditcl. "-S socket" does not work in my ubuntu, but the code below (optionally adding -F pid=`pgrep -x yourApplication` ) is quite good spotting socket creations

```
auditctl -a exit,always   -S socketcall -F uid=$USER -F a0=1 -F a3=1  -k OPEN_SOCKETS
```