# Find source of outgoing traffic to specific UDP port

Tags: iptables, logging, centos6

Since a few days ago I've been observing some strange recurrent outgoing UDP traffic from my server on port 24441 but since it's not constant, I cannot seem to find what's causing it.

All I can see is the following in iptables logs:

```
Nov 15 00:46:33 server kernel: [17216276.676673] Firewall: *UDP_OUT Blocked* IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=<SERVER_IP> DST=5.9.124.53 LEN=192 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=60641 DPT=24441 LEN=172 UID=501 GID=513
```

I suspect it's some kind of malware running periodically from my server but want to find out what exactly.
Can someone shed a light on how to catch this/log the source of this automatically when it happens? I'm running Centos 6.7. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Found the answer in a related thread: http://serverfault.com/questions/192893/how-i-can-identify-which-process-is-making-udp-traffic-on-linux

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this, it seems the outgoing UDP connections were caused by Apache's SpamAssassin through "spamd child" process. I assume when it was actually catching some spam since the time intervals appeared as random. I've disabled SpamAssassin for now just to see if it happens again.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, run continuously, but I haven't tested it :) .

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -f iptables.log | grep "UDP_OUT Blocked" | sed 's/^.*SPT=//g
s/\s.*$//g' | ( while read portnum
do
    netstat --inet --program --udp --all -v -n | grep "$portnum"
done ) 2>&1 | tee suspicious.log
```

Tail, grep, sed extract a list of source port numbers that have been blocked, and netstat gets the program information.

Comment: Thanks, tried that but didn't get anything logged to 'suspicious.log' even though another even had occurred while the script was running.

Comment: @Ivan sorry about that - fixed a bug in the script.  Give it a try now.